# Merge RGB channels in ImageJ Javascript macro

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej, imagej-macro

I'm reading in cropped areas from three channel .svs images and saving the crops as .tiff images. Currently, the images are saving with separate RGB channels.

I crop the image this way:

```
var path = currentFolder + "images" + File.separator + imageName; 
var options = new ImporterOptions(); 
options.setId(path); 
options.setAutoscale(true); 
options.setCrop(true); 
options.setCropRegion(0, new Region(X, Y, deltaX, deltaY)); 
options.setColorMode(ImporterOptions.COLOR_MODE_COMPOSITE); 
var croppedImage= new ImagePlus();
croppedImage= BF.openImagePlus(options); 

print("cropped image class: " + croppedImage.getClass());
```

gives

```
cropped image class: class [Lij.ImagePlus;
```

Then I save the images:

```
IJ.saveAs(cropedImage, "tif", outputFileName);
```

I end up with three channel images.

[image]

I want to merge the channels.

I found two potential ways to do this:

http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/ij/plugin/RGBStackMerge.html

http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ImagePlus.html#flatten--

I tried `croppedImage.flatten()` and got:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Java class "[Lij.ImagePlus;" has no public instance field or method named "flatten".
```

I also tried importing the `RGBStackMerge` class:

```
importClass(Packages.ij.plugin.RGBStackMerge);
```

and doing

```
finalImage = new ImagePlus();
finalImage = RGBStackMerge.mergeChannels(croppedImage, false);
print ("final image class: " + finalImage.getClass() + " length: " + finalImage.length);
```

But this gives:

```
Started svs_to_cropped_tiffs.js at Fri Jan 22 22:58:10 PST 2016 javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "getClass" of null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`BF` class javadoc](http://javadoc.imagej.net/Bio-Formats/index.html?loci/plugins/BF.html):

> `static ImagePlus[]          openImagePlus(ImporterOptions options)`

`BF.openImagePlus()` returns an **array** of `ImagePlus` objects (indicated by `[L` in your `getClass()` output).
You should access your image by accessing the first element of the returned array: `croppedImage[0]`

Both of your suggested methods should work then:

```
finalImage = croppedImage[0].flatten();
```

or

```
finalImage = RGBStackMerge.mergeChannels(croppedImage[0], false);
```

---

You can find **examples how to open images using Bio-Formats** on the [Scripting toolbox](http://imagej.net/Scripting_toolbox#Opening_an_image_using_Bio-Formats) page on the ImageJ wiki.

Comment: the first method did work! I tried the 2nd and got `javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Can't find method ij.plugin.RGBStackMerge.mergeChannels(loci.plugins.in.Colorizer$1,boolean).` I'm accepting your answer, but if you know what might be going wrong with `mergeChannels`, I'd love to know.